# JCombo AutoComplete - Pattern or Reverse Lookup

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, autocomplete, jcombobox

I'm using the [auto-complete decorator in the swingx library](http://download.java.net/javadesktop/swinglabs/releases/0.8/docs/api/org/jdesktop/swingx/autocomplete/package-summary.html):

`AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate( myComboBox );`

Which is pretty sweet. However, it only searches forward from the start of the typed text.

So if my combo contains: [Apple, Banana, Grape, Orange] typing 'an' in "strict" mode will not show any results. In non-strict mode nothing is searched either. I'd like it to match 'Banana' & 'Orange' since both items contain my typed text.

Are there any auto-complete libraries that allow for this type of functionality? I would think a strategy approach would work best here, but I'm not finding anything applicable. I'm fine with extending existing functionality - so long as I'm not reinventing the wheel.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

AutoComplete for `JComboBox` and `JTextField` and by your requirements here you can sets strict false/true [Auto complete ComboBox / JFextField](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/AutocompleteComboBox.htm) and if you'll want to play with code then that's good base for AutoComplete funcionalities for `JFormattedTextField`

Comment: I tested the code out on the link you've provided below - there isn't anything that indicates that it is any different than the swingx library. It does not seem to have any pattern based matching.

Comment: that's time to post code showing what did you ... and tried :-)

Comment: I used the code from the link you provided as it is. It did not have pattern matching auto-complete; only forward searching. I then modified the code to use matches (and wrapped it in a simple regex), but this messed up the highlighter. It's not worth it for me to muck around with it - the functionality either exists out of the box or it doesn't. It seems like this functionality does not. But thanks anyways.

Comment: I'm not sure what you tried, maybe there is ...:-), you have to deep look into "Matcher" and add/change required code, anyway that's very interesting what you described, and why not post your code here???

Comment: Have you got any solution ? I need the same. To make AutoCompleteDecorator -match pattern ,not forward searching.