# JFrame Combo box Event Key... HELP

Tags: java, events, keypress, jcombobox, jform

I am having a problem on what to use and what to code if I want my combo box be generated once the user type a key...

like:

once i pressed letter "A" from keyboard inside the combo box, all items starting from letter "A" will show up from the drop down list.

How can I code this when:

items from the combo box came from my database and it's default value is the first item stored on my database.

Actually I don't have any idea how to code it.  All I have was a template from JFrame.

Items from database were just drag to combo box and it automatically generate a class.

Please Help.  Thanks in advance ^_^

Comment: "Please Help."  [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).  "Thanks in advance"  You're welcome.

Comment: are you meaning AutoComplete(d) JComboBox, agreed with Andrew Thompson,

Comment: Wow... thanks for the link Sir Andrew Thompson... this will help a lot.. for me to ask question effectively next time... anyway... because of your kindness, can you help me about my problem at event handling... I only know basics... so I am looking for someone that can help me solve my problem... if you have something you don't understand regarding my question, i'll try my best to explain my problem more effective as i can... thanks again in advance ^_^

Comment: @mKorbe, yes.. something like that... but it was in jcombo box form... not in textfield. Hope you can help me... thanks in advance ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok here is go two classes one for JComboBox and 2nd for JTextField (you are neede both)
you can set for both if is strict (if Iten Exist) or not you can input any value as you wants [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020769/jcombo-autocomplete-pattern-or-reverse-lookup/6020902#6020902)

much luck