# How to set JChoice (JComboBox) in JTextField like a search box?

Tags: java, swing

I am working on a project to make a Web browser in Java Swing.

I want to set a combo box within a Jtextfield, like the search box of browser.

Comment: What have you tried? You are much more likely to get a useful answer if you explain exactly what the problem is and provide a short, complete piece of code that illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

are you meaning [AutoComplete(d) JComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386289/jframe-combo-box-event-key-help)